# Optimizing an algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

**Problem**: Let's say we have a set of n vertices A = {0, 1,..., n-1} and we are given some set B of triangles whose vertices are in A. So, for example, we could have n = 5 and B = {[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4]} (but not [1, 2, 2] because triangles need to be non-degenerate). From there you can generate new triangles by glueing them together by the following rule: take three triangles such that each two have exactly one common edge and all three of them have exactly one vertex in common
[(see the image).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU7Fr.png)
For example, the three triangles above would be glued to create a triangle [1, 3, 4]. My goal is to write an algorithm would then continue to create new triangles until it could, and then check if it could generate all n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 6 possible non-degenerate triangles.

Here's my code in python:

```
import random

# lists all the pairs of distinct integers in [0, n - 1]
def connections(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            result.append([i, j])
    return result

# makes a list of all possible triangles with vertices in [0, n - 1] 
def all_faces(n):
    result = []
    for i in connections(n):
        for j in range(i[1] + 1, n):
            result.append(i + [j])
    return result

def my_algorithm(n, faces):
        generalized_faces = faces
        new_faces = [] 
        number_new_faces = len(generalized_faces)     
        i = 0

# generate new triangles from the existing ones in generalized_faces
# and then add them in new_faces. Repeat the loop while new_faces is nonempty.

        while len(new_faces) > 0 or i == 0:
            generalized_faces.extend(new_faces)
            length = len(generalized_faces)              
            if i > 0:
                number_new_faces = len(new_faces)
                new_faces = []
            if length == n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 6:  
                return True      
            for i in range(length - number_new_faces, length):
                [a, b, c] = generalized_faces[i]
                for j in range(n):
                    if j not in [a, b, c]:
                        triangle1 = [a, b, j]
                        triangle1.sort()
                        triangle2 = [b, c, j]
                        triangle2.sort()
                        triangle3 = [a, c, j]
                        triangle3.sort()
                        if triangle1 in new_faces + generalized_faces and triangle2 in new_faces + generalized_faces:
                            final_triangle = [a, c, j]
                            final_triangle.sort()
                            if final_triangle not in new_faces + generalized_faces:
                                new_faces.append(final_triangle)
                        if triangle1 in new_faces + generalized_faces and triangle3 in new_faces + generalized_faces:
                            final_triangle = [b, c, j]
                            final_triangle.sort()
                            if final_triangle not in new_faces + generalized_faces:
                                new_faces.append(final_triangle)
                        if triangle2 in new_faces + generalized_faces and triangle3 in new_faces + generalized_faces:
                            final_triangle = [a, b, j]
                            final_triangle.sort()
                            if final_triangle not in new_faces + generalized_faces:
                                new_faces.append(final_triangle)
                    
            i += 1
        return len(generalized_faces) == n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 6

# returns some subset of all_faces(n)
def choose_faces(n, p):
    return [x for x in all_faces(n) if random.random() < p]

# tests the probability of success in m trials depending on probability p
def test(n, m, p):
    result = 0.0
    for _ in range(m):
        faces = choose_faces(n, p)
        if my_algorithm(n, faces):
            result += 1.0
    return result/(float(m))
```

There are two problems that I've encountered:

- my code is incredibly slow, even at only n = 30.
- some of the outputs looked suspect but I couldn't find the error.

My question is this: is it possible to make this algorithm run fast for, say, n = 1000 with B being a reasonably large subset of all possible non-degenerate triangles on n vertices?
If so, what would be a possible implementation?

Comment: I propose to look at [Numba package](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/5minguide.html), extract parts of code that are your bottlnecks as separate functions and optimize them using Numba.

Comment: I'm almost certain that your glueing process generates all triangles if and only if all edges are present at least once in B and the graph formed by the edges that are present exactly once in B does not contain a chordless cycle of length greater than 3. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to formally prove it. Something to do with the possible configurations of single edges (those present exactly once in B) and their corresponding triangles.

Comment: Never mind, I found a counterexample. Perhaps a better criterion is that, for every vertex, at least two triangles in B must share this vertex and an edge.

Answer (score 0):

*I'll take the bait....*

I'm not sure if you need the triangle-gluing rule at all, unless that is mandated.

Why isn't this sufficient:

```
from itertools import combinations
all_triangles = combinations(A, 3)
```

This will produce a generator that will generate all 3-vertex combinations without repeats, and without degenerates.

Comment: Maybe I didn't word this correctly, but I'm not looking for a function that would generate all triplets without repetition. I'm looking for a function that would check whether the set B of triangles generates all such triplets using nothing but the above triangle glueing rule.

Comment: @the_dude Well, that is not what your original question asked.  Checking the output of your algorithm is different than making it, which is what you asked about.  You could use the output above and compare it to yours, if desired.  Your orig algorithm has some inefficiencies, but I’m confused by the fact that it isn’t implementing any “gluing” of triangles.  All you are doing is picking 3 points (a face) and them making all possible triangles from that point to another randomly selected point, which is quite different approach

Comment: @AirSquid His algorithm *does* implement the glueing operation. It's what the `for j in range(n)` loop does.

Comment: @Nelfeal  Oh, I disagree.  I see the loop over "j", but it is not gluing triangles together.  It is creating new triangles by picking an edge of the *existing* triangle [a, b, c] to the vertex j.  If we were gluing triangles together with a common vertex, the result would be what we started with, [a, b, c] iff j is interior to them.

Comment: @AirSquid Not sure what you mean with "[a, b, c] iff j is interior to them", but here's what the code inside that loop does: with `[a, b, c]` in `generalized_faces`, take another vertex `j` and check if the tetrahedron `[a, b, c, j]` has two more faces in `new_faces + generalized_faces`, and if so, add the last face to `new_faces` if it isn't already in there. This is literally the glueing operation: take three triangles such that each pair share a different edge, and create the triangle that would close the tetrahedron.

Comment: @Nelfeal.  Not sure why we are digging in here...  lol.  I see your point, but if point `j` is external to `[a, b, c]` then there will be overlap amongst triangles which include point `j`....  I wouldn't consider that "gluing" together, and the resultant triangle may not be the sum of the faces of the other 2.

Comment: @AirSquid Ok I get the confusion. OP confirmed that the overlap can happen and doesn't invalidate a "glueing" operation, but that was in a comment to a now deleted answer. I agree that "glueing" might not be the most descriptive term for this. Your answer is still off-topic though.